# Sum two values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, sum

this I think will be stupid question, but here it goes.

I need to dynamically add a div and give it ID + 1 depending on last added div's ID of previously added element.

the div is

```
<div id="file-uploader-0" class="file-uploader"></div>
```

So I roughly came out with that code:

```
$('#addOneMoreFileOrGroup').on('click', function(){

    var latestFileUploaderId = $('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2] + 1;

    $('.well-large .control-group:last').after('<div class="control-group deal-type-online">  \
            <label class="control-label">File / File Group Title:</label> \
            <div class="controls"> \
                <input class="span4 file-title" type="text"> \
                <span class="question label label-warning" data-title="File / Group Name:" data-content="Name for your file or group of related files (for example your brand logotype in different file formats)." data-original-title="">?</span> \
                <div id="file-uploader-' + latestFileUploaderId + '" class="file-uploader"></div> \
            </div> \
        </div>');

    });
```

But the problem is that in the end of all that I receive "file-uploader-01", "file-uploader-011", "file-uploader-0111".

I tried to use "latestFileUploaderId++" which giving me right result once as "1" and after going as "11", "111", "1111".

Thank you for the tips and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a string to a number, which causes the `+` operator to do string concatenation.

Convert the string to a number first.

```
var latestFileUploaderId = parseFloat($('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2]) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quite easy.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
var latestFileUploaderId = $('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2] + 1;
```

to this:

```
var latestFileUploaderId = parseInt($('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2],10) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string from the id to integer to increment it correctly:

```
var lastID = parseInt($('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2]);
var latestFileUploaderId = lastID + 1;
```

Comment: some commmentary would help this answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var latestFileUploaderId = parseInt($('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2],10) + 1;
```

You are cocatenating a string and a number... parseInt will convert the string to its numerical value and then the addition will work.

Comment: Note that you should always declare the radix to be safe. While this parameter is optional, always specify it to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `parseInt`:

```
var latestFileUploaderId = parseInt($('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2]) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseInt()` to convert the id to a number.

```
var latestFileUploaderId = parseInt($('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2]) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2]
```

is a string. You need to parse it to a int(float).
try using parseInt, parseFloat

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the value to a Number. Like this:

```
var latestFileUploaderId = Number($('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2]) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to change the variable to a Number first, but I wouldn't use parseInt() or similar. Instead, multiplying by 1 is much faster, so something like this is what I'd recommend:

```
var last = $('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2];
var latestFileUploaderId = (last * 1) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses the + operator to concatenate strings which happens in your case. Only numerical types are summarized arithmetically.
In order to increment the ID you have to cast it to an integer before.

```
console.log ('1' + 1 ); 
String '11'

console.log( parseInt('1') + 1 )
Int 2
```